# Scanning subfolders with BASH Script ${ROOTPATH}/${subdir}

Tags: bash, scripting, ffmpeg, move

Doing my best to make this work but have little knowledge of scripting. This script should be scanning my specified directory and all subdirs scanning video assets moving any corrupted/errored files to the 00errors folder which has been created.

I can get everything to work accept scanning all the sub dirs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOTPATH="/Volumes/ARC-RAID/STORAGE/ASSET-Processing/Movies/LANDSCAPE/BRAND-RECOVERED/BRAND-RECOVERED-LANDSCAPE "
for subdir in *; do
  cd ${ROOTPATH}/${subdir}
  mkdir 00errors
  
  for path in *.{MOV,mov,MP4,mp4}; do

    ffmpeg -i "${path}" -f null -; echo$?
    RC=$?

    if [ "${RC}" -ne "0" ]; then
        # Do something to handle the error.
        mv ${path} ./00errors
    fi

  done
  cd ../
done
```

Comment: You haven't been very specific about (a) what you expect to happen and (b) what is actually happening, but I suspect you want `for subdir in "${ROOTPATH}"/*; do cd "${subdir}" ...; cd -`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you. I have little knowledge in this area and have no idea what the modification you suggested does differently. I replaced [ for subdir in *; do
  cd ${ROOTPATH}/${subdir} ] with what you suggested and now the command just errors on every file in the main dir and does nothing. If you can provide me with what you think the proper and actual code would be that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "just errors"? the only other thing I just noticed is that your `ROOTPATH` appears to have a trailing space character - is that intentional?

Comment: ... also `echo$?` will result in an error; `echo $?; RC=$?` will result in `RC` containing the exit status of `echo` (if you want to both echo `$?` and test it, save the value first). You may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not looking too carefully at your code but suggesting that you use `find` instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

topdir=/Volumes/ARC-RAID/STORAGE/ASSET-Processing/Movies/LANDSCAPE/BRAND-RECOVERED/BRAND-RECOVERED-LANDSCAPE

find "$topdir" -name 00error -prune -o \
    -type f \( -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.mov' \) \
    ! -exec ffmpeg -i {} -f null /dev/null \; \
    -execdir mkdir -p 00error \; \
    -execdir mv -- {} 00error \;
```

Or, calling a short in-line `sh` script from `find`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

topdir=/Volumes/ARC-RAID/STORAGE/ASSET-Processing/Movies/LANDSCAPE/BRAND-RECOVERED/BRAND-RECOVERED-LANDSCAPE

find "$topdir" -name 00error -prune -o \
    -type f \( -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.mov' \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if ! ffmpeg -i "$pathname" -f null /dev/null; then
            dirpath=${pathname%/*}
            mkdir -p "$dirpath"/00error
            mv "$pathname" "$dirpath"/00error
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

Both of these variations assume that you have a `find` that understands `-iname` for matching a pattern case-insensitively against filenames, and that it understands `-execdir`, which executes a utility in the directory of the found file.  Both `-iname` and `-execdir` are non-standard.

This would pick up any movie file anywhere under the top directory, so it's not as strict about the directory structure as your script.

---

About your code:

- I notice that the value of `ROOTPATH` has a space at the end.  This is possibly accidental.
- `echo$?` will try to execute something like `echo0` or `echo1` or something similar, due to the missing space between `echo` and `$?`.
- Fixing the above typo would cause the shell to overwrite `$?` with the exit status of `echo`, so `$RC` would later not reflect the exit status of `ffmpeg`, but that of `echo`.
- Rather than saving the exit status of a command in a separate variable and then testing this against zero, use the command directly in the `if` statement.  I did this in the second variation of the `find` command above.
- `*` may match both directory names and the names of non-directories.  Using `cd ${ROOTPATH}/${subdir}` could therefore fail (it could also fail due to spaces in directory names, like that space at the end of `ROOTPATH` that you have, or due to the directory being empty).  If that `cd` fails, your inner loop could potentially process the wrong files, and the `cd ..` further down would bring you up a level too high.

This is a corrected variant of your code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

topdir=/Volumes/ARC-RAID/STORAGE/ASSET-Processing/Movies/LANDSCAPE/BRAND-RECOVERED/BRAND-RECOVERED-LANDSCAPE

# Make globbing case-insensitive (nocaseglob), and
# make patterns disappear if not matched (nullglob)
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for subdir in "$topdir"/*/; do
    for mov in "$subdir"/*.{mov,mp4}; do
        if [ -f "$mov" ] && ! ffmpeg -i "$mov" -f null /dev/null; then
            mkdir -p "$subdir"/00error &&
            mv "$mov" "$subdir"/00error
        fi
    done
done
```

As you see, `cd` is not necessary.

Without the inner loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

topdir=/Volumes/ARC-RAID/STORAGE/ASSET-Processing/Movies/LANDSCAPE/BRAND-RECOVERED/BRAND-RECOVERED-LANDSCAPE

shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob

for mov in "$topdir"/*/*.{mov,mp4}; do
    if [ -f "$mov" ] && ! ffmpeg -i "$mov" -f null /dev/null; then
        mkdir -p "${mov%/*}"/00error &&
        mv "$mov" "${mov%/*}"/00error
    fi
done
```